# Not fully understanding the outputs of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose you have a basis $v_1,...,v_n$ of $V$ and $w_1,...,w_n  \in W$. Where the vectors in W are not necessarily a basis of W.

Let's say we also have a vector in V written as $v=a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n$

If we apply the linear map we get the following:
$T(a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n)=c_1w_1+...+c_nw_n$

I don't understand how the scalars on the LHS are the same scalars on the LHS.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: They won't be the same unless you're assuming $T(v_i)=w_i$.  Linearity gives your left-hand side equal to $a_1T(v_1)+ \cdots + a_nT(v_n)$.

Comment: I am assuming that $T(v_1)=w_i$.

Comment: Also, without defining everything better, "we get the following" is false.

Comment: Then the answer is "this is the defintion of linearity."

Comment: Thank you I forgot the fact that with linearity you can pull the scalars out which would be $T(a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n)=a_1T(v_1)+...+a_nT(v_n)=a_1w_1+...+a_nw_n$

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any linear map between vector spaces is completely defined by the images of the basis vectors of our domain. We define $t(v_i) = w_i$ and saying we want the corresponding linear map $T:V\to W$, such that $T$ restricted to the basis of V is t, makes the equation $T(v) = T(\lambda_1 v_1+\dots +\lambda_n v_n) = \lambda_1 T(v_1)+\dots + \lambda_n T(v_n) = \lambda_1 w_1+\dots\lambda_n w_n$ a necessaity as it is the only linear map satisfying the condition that it restricts to t.